# Gulp not found when running gulp serve

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

```
 @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.18.0
gulp-cli@2.3.0
├── gulp@4.0.2
└── yo@4.3.1
```

it's showing these version but
when I use `gulp bundle`
it's giving error:

```
gulp : The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First run this in powershell `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` and check `Get-ExecutionPolicy` and get like this....

[image]

2. Next run this `npm install gulp-cli yo @microsoft/generator-sharepoint --global`
3. Check the version of gulp by using `gulp --v` or `gulp --version` and get like this..

[image]

3. and next `gulp trust-dev-cert`

and you can run deploy commands i.e., `gulp build`

Answer (score 0):

You should not have both `gulp` and `gulp-cli` installed.

From the [Exercise - Configure your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/sharepoint-spfx-get-started/5-exercise-setup-development-environment) module of the [Get started with the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/sharepoint-spfx-get-started/) unit on Microsoft Learn.

[image: Gulp CLI install instructions]

For more detail see this blog post by Andrew Connell, [Mea culpa - always install gulp-cli globally, not gulp](https://www.voitanos.io/blog/mea-culpa-always-install-gulp-cli-globally-not-gulp/).

Comment: then also it's showing same gulp command was not found

Comment: after uninstalling gulp now i have gulp cli 2.3.0